# connection level dataBase - how to edit tables

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dll

***using*** c#, .net Framwork 4.5, VS 12

Try to understand connection level of database access.
***This Question has long explanation!***

Currently create database, simple procedure, dll for work with data base and Console app for access to db.

***Few words about created:***

My data base next :

[image]

Procedure - `GetPetName`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetPetName  (   @carId int, @petName char(10) OUTPUT )
AS
SELECT @petName = PetName from Inventory where CarId = @carId
```

also in dll i create connection for my DB, and in console app try to use method from this Dll.

Problem, is that few method not work, and have no idea why - checked few times methods, but has no result. Also method for updating information and showing all info from DB works.

Problemic methods, and problems that i have with it - described below:

1. Method for using Procedure from DB

   ```
   public string LookUpPetName(int CarID)
   {
       string CarPetName = string.Empty;
       using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetPetName", this.sqlCn))
       {
           cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

           SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
           param.ParameterName = "@carID";
           param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
           param.Value = CarID;
           param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
           cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

           param = new SqlParameter();
           param.ParameterName = "@petName";
           param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Char;
           param.Size = 10;
           param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
           cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

           CarPetName = (string)cmd.Parameters["petName"].Value;
       }
       return CarPetName;
   }
   }
   ```

with this method, when I try to call it got error message - problem with next desciprion `SQLParameter with SQLParameterName "petName" don't exist in your SQLParameterCollection`. But as I understand I return `petName` using my procedure `GetPetName`.

**Question number 1** - Am I correctly understand usage of procedure from db? If no - please explain it for me, if yes, why i got such result.

The second method is created for inserting entries in my table - here i mede next

```
 public void InsertoAuto(int CarID, string Color,
        string Make, string PetName)
    {
        string sql = string.Format("Insert into Inventory"
            + " (CarID, Make, Color, PetName) Values"
            + ("@mycarID, @Make, @Color, @PetName"));

        using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, this.sqlCn))
        {
            //add parameters - help to avoid attacks, 
            //make request a little bit faster
            SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "@mycarID";
            param.Value = CarID;
            param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(param);

            param = new SqlParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "@Make";
            param.Value = Make;
            param.Size = 10;
            param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Char;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(param);

            param = new SqlParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "@Color";
            param.Value = Color;
            param.Size = 10;
            param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Char;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(param);

            param = new SqlParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "@PetName";
            param.Value = PetName;
            param.Size = 10;
            param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Char;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(param);

            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

and the second variant for insertion (using some entities)

```
 public void UpdateCarPetName (int carId, string carName)
    {
        string sql = string.Format("Update Inventory Set PetName = '{0}' Where CarID = '{1}'",
            carName, carId);
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlCn))
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

When i try to call this method  - both (note: I got before calling methods one int value and 3 string values), i got error with description - `incorrect syntacsis for "@mycarID"` for first method and `incorrect syntacsis for PetName` for second variant. But if all parameters ok for string values - whats wrong for this one. Check also (as you can see abowe), that in table used the same types of variables.

**Question number 2** - Where i wrong with this methods, and why i can't take int parameter?

Also during creating dll for working with my dataBase found, that I can't check my methods in Dll for functionality if I not use it with another project.

**Additional question** - is there are some method for checking methods during creating DLL, or I always must to create some "supporting" project for parallel cheking workability of my dll? Means how can i make debug step-by-step during creating?

*Thnik a lot of question for one post, but put it together for reduction of explanation part for question in others posts.*

Comment: In the stored procedure you are not executing the command

Comment: Before `CarPetName = (string)cmd.Parameters["petName"].Value;` should should execute the command.

Comment: like `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` ?

Comment: Yes, you should also put an `@` before the parameter name `(string)cmd.Parameters["@petName"].Value;`

Comment: Oh, really, - now this works, don't now how I miss it.... Thanks, and how about other questions?

Comment: In the first method: you are keeping your parenthesis out of the query string `("@mycarID, @Make, @Color, @PetName")`. Should be `"(@mycarID, @Make, @Color, @PetName)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first method change the last lines to:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
CarPetName = (string)cmd.Parameters["@petName"].Value;
```

you are not executing the command and also note the `@` before the parameter name.

In the second method you are keeping the parenthesis outside your query:

```
+ ("@mycarID, @Make, @Color, @PetName"));
```

should be

```
+ "(@mycarID, @Make, @Color, @PetName)");  // note the parenthesis inside the string
```

In the third method you are comparing `CarId` with a string

```
Where CarID = '{1}'
```

Should be

```
Where CarID = {1}
```

Well, it shouldn't: you should use parameters as you did before.

Comment: Thanks - now all ok, and how abut any advice for debaging dll? Are ther is some method or i always must to create "supporting" project?

Comment: For now I'd suggest you to create "supporting projects" and learn how to proficiently use the debugger. Than read something about testing and unit testing frameworks.